# Codemagic Skip publishing to App Store Connect: no IPAs or PKGs found

Tags: ionic-framework, testflight, capacitor, codemagic

I use CodeMagic for CI/CD on an Ionic application with Capacitor and VueJS. The whole build process goes very well, up to the publishing process. I have this final log that makes the app not be sent to TestFlight :

Skip publishing to App Store Connect: no IPAs or PKGs found

ID : 63b942a48ab154742fe6b4d9

I have the codemagic.yml configuration for Ionic and Capacitor...
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/56630992/211145195-f9233bce-34d0-40a2-86ae-23bf2b936a52.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/56630992/211145181-55a2ec19-5a23-417e-b416-f3a994bb935a.png

Thanks in advance

I have these lines into the codemagic.yml file :

```
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `artifacts` path starts from the repository root and correct one.

Also you can use absolute path like `$CM_BUILD_DIR/ios/App/build/ios/ipa/*.ipa`